# Equivalent of DefaultLabel in primefaces 3.2

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, primefaces

Please, Is it an equivalent of DefaultLabel (Combobox of richfaces) in Primefaces 3.2 ?

Regards .

Comment: `rich:select` tag component in RichFaces 4.x

Comment: This is from richfaces but I need from primefaces

Answer (score 1):

**SelectOneMenu** (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf) is the equivalent in primefaces. All the components provided by primefaces can be checked at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf